# Batch overlay logo to directory of video files

Tags: batch-file, video, ffmpeg

I am using this command in windows 8 to overlay a **logo (mywatermark.png , 400x200)** to a video file:

```
ffmpeg -i E:\source\video01.mp4 -i E:\logo\mywatermark.png -filter_complex "[1:v]scale=100:50 [ovrl], [0:v][ovrl
]overlay=W-w-10:H-h-10[watermark]" -map "[watermark]" -map 0:a -codec:v libx264 -preset veryfast -crf 18 -codec:a copy E:\output\video01.mp4
```

as you can see I am first rescaling my logo to 100:50 pixels, and then overlaying it to the bottom right corner.
This is working for me.

**My question is:** 
How can I repeat this to all of the videos in the same directory, adding the same logo to all?
I want to save the output video files same as the original, of course in different folder. However, not to forget that my source video files are of different quality and resolution.
How can I add a parameter to the command line to proportionnally scale the logo in regard to the video file resolution? 
I am afraid that if I don't do this, the logo will be small in one file and bigger in another.

thanks a lot

Comment: @Mofi could you please write it as an answer, a working example. plz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I repeat this to all of the videos in the same directory, adding the same logo to all?

Windows command line processor - `cmd.exe` - offers the command **FOR** for executing a command on all files in a directory.

```
@echo off
for %%I in ("E:\source\*.mp4") do ffmpeg.exe -i "%%I" -i E:\logo\mywatermark.png -filter_complex "[1:v]scale=100:50 [ovrl], [0:v][ovrl]overlay=W-w-10:H-h-10[watermark]" -map "[watermark]" -map 0:a -codec:v libx264 -preset veryfast -crf 18 -codec:a copy "E:\output\%%~nI.mp4"
```

Running in a command prompt window `for /?` or `help for` outputs help for this command over several display pages. As help of command **FOR** is long, it is advisable to redirect the output help into a text file and read the file with Notepad or any other text editor.

```
for /? >"%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\Help_FOR.txt"
Notepad "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\Help_FOR.txt"
```

In above batch code `%%I` is replaced by name of current *.mp4 file with full path and `%%~nI` with just name of current *.mp4 file without path and without file extension.

Answer (score 1):

As @LordNeckbeard commented, you can use the `scale2ref` filter to proportionally scale the watermark, like so

```
ffmpeg -i E:\source\video01.mp4 -loop 1 -i E:\logo\mywatermark.png \
-filter_complex "[1:v][0:v]scale2ref=iw/8:-1[ovrl][0v]; \
[0v][ovrl]overlay=W-w-10:H-h-10[watermark]" \
-map "[watermark]" -map 0:a \
-codec:v libx264 -preset veryfast -crf 18 -c:a copy E:\output\video01.mp4
```

The `iw/8` specifies that the watermark's width and height be scaled to 1/8th of the base video's width and height. The `scale2ref` filter has the same options available as the `scale` filter.

Comment: I've corrected my command - I had forgotten an output pad. Should work now.